# Bookshelf JS undefined throughTableName

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to get the `filenames` from the `files` table through the `attachments` table for a post.

The attachments table:

```
post_id, file_id
```

The files table:

```
id, filename
```

The post table

```
attachments = 1,2,3
```

The attachments column in the post table contains a list of attachment_id.
I want to get each of the filename of those 1,2,3 attachments.

So I made a relationship,

My post model:

```
require('./file');
require('./attachment');

...

attachments: function() {
  return console.log(this.hasMany('File').through('Attachment'));
},
```

The console.log shows:

```
{ type: 'hasMany',
 target: 
  { [Function]
    extend: [Function],
    include: [Function],
    __super__: [Object],
    forge: [Function],
    collection: [Function] },
 targetTableName: 'files',
 targetIdAttribute: 'id',
 foreignKey: undefined,
 parentId: 1,
 parentTableName: 'posts',
 parentIdAttribute: 'id',
 parentFk: 1,
 throughTarget: 'Attachment',
 throughTableName: undefined,
 throughIdAttribute: undefined,
 throughForeignKey: undefined,
 otherKey: undefined },
```

First question is, why is it not detecting Attachments table name? I have already set it like so:

```
var Attachment = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'attachments'
});

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Attachment', Attachment);
```

And finally when I query the page it only returns `{}` why? Just a beginner.

I am also using registry on all model files

```
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, fixed in 0.6.6 release.